# Core Data tutorials

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

Is there any good Core Data tutorials out there for mac/cocoa(not iphone)?

Comment: [**Here**](http://www.rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2013/04/simple-and-basic-coredata-in-iphone.html) is the simple step by step tutorial for CoreData for Beginners, hope it will help you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one for OS X: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21752/how-to-use-cocoa-bindings-and-core-data-in-a-mac-app

This is a good one as well (iOS):
http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: How is this the selected answer? It says __(not iphone)__!

Comment: The beauty of Core Data is that the concepts transfer from OSX to iOS and back. Is there a particular problem you found with the tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

What about the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)?

And, except for XML Storage and support for Cocoa Bindings, Core Data is (exactly?) the same in both Mac OS X and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

it's not free but the book "More iPhone 3 Development Tackling the iPhone SDK" has several chapters on core data. I know it's not for iPhone but it's got a lot of what you need to know. also "Cocoa Programming Developer's Handbook" is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I came across a short but insightful text on Core Data as it is used with **cocoa**. Take a look at this at [cocoadevcentral.com](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000086.php). Have fun!